# Javascript error document.getElementById('x').style.display='none'

Tags: javascript, php, html

What is wrong on this syntax:
PHP

```
echo '<li onMouseOver="" onMouseOut="document.getElementById(\''.$boxrow.'\').style.display=\'none\';">';
```

And on HTML page source code:

```
<li onmouseover="" onmouseout="document.getElementById('evidence').style.display='none';">
```

IT is working fine, but scripts after this wil causing errors, if I remove this script everything working fine.

First what is below this script and stop working is:

```
header("Location: index.php?module=service&no=".$_POST['id']."&"); and next after ...
```

Comment: Nothing obvious, but you don't really want to be using inline statements; consider refactoring your code so JS instructions like that are handled centrally from within a script, not muddled amongst your HTML. There are a host of advantages, ease of maintenance and cleanliness of code to name but two.

Comment: you mean make a functions outside? like onmouseout="dohide('evidence')"? Result is the same.. :-(

Comment: header code should be on top of any echo or print . otherwise php will throw an error

Comment: No, I mean learn about targeting DOM elements from within central scripts called from `<script>` tags rather than bundling your JS inline amongst your HTML. What you are doing is called inline DOM-zero event handling, and it's very outdated. Look into centralised event handling. Consider jQuery, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP header redirection only works if you still didn't parse any code on your page. Try redirect by javascript instead.

Also it's a better practice not to use inline javascript. Better:

EDIT:

```
window.onload = function() {
    li.onmouseout=function(){
       document.getElementById('evidence').style.display='none';
    };
};
```

Comment: Of course not, the code before was an illustrative example about unobstrusive Javascript. Edited.

Comment: header redirect should be on top of any ofthe echo or print statement.

Comment: SHIN: Is this different to what I stated?

Comment: Header is first after the <body> tag, upper is only <head>